# web-starter-kit getting started, a syntax error running gulp for the first time in plugin gulp-ruby-sass

Tags: gulp

I'm trying web-starter-kit. I followed installation instructions and I receive a error log that interpretation I'm not really sure about. I'm still in the getting started phase, I get the error running gulp in the web-starter-kit/app folder. I'm totally inexperienced with this technology and I'm working with the default resources included in the starting folder. I couldn't find anything useful on the internet. This is the error log:

```
[13:26:16] Working directory changed to ~/Desktop/web-starter-kit
[13:26:17] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/web-starter-kit/gulpfile.js
[13:26:17] Starting 'clean'...
[13:26:17] Finished 'clean' after 4.43 ms
[13:26:17] Starting 'default'...
[13:26:17] Starting 'styles:components'...
[13:26:17] Starting 'styles:scss'...
[13:26:17] Starting 'styles:css'...
[13:26:17] gulp-size: 'styles:css' total 0 B
[13:26:17] Finished 'styles:css' after 94 ms
[13:26:17] gulp-size: 'styles:scss' total 0 B
[13:26:17] Finished 'styles:scss' after 110 ms
[13:26:17] [gulp-ruby-sass] 
Syntax error: Mixin "medium" does not accept a content block.
    on line 160 of /home/riccardo/Desktop/web-starter-kit/app/styles/components/_utils.scss, in `medium'
    from line 160 of /home/riccardo/Desktop/web-starter-kit/app/styles/components/_utils.scss, in `container'
    from line 32 of /home/riccardo/Desktop/web-starter-kit/app/styles/components/_global.scss
    from line 10 of /home/riccardo/Desktop/web-starter-kit/app/styles/components/components.scss


events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error in plugin 'gulp-ruby-sass'

Syntax error: Mixin "medium" does not accept a content block.
    on line 160 of /home/riccardo/Desktop/web-starter-kit/app/styles/components/_utils.scss, in `medium'
    from line 160 of /home/riccardo/Desktop/web-starter-kit/app/styles/components/_utils.scss, in `container'
    from line 32 of /home/riccardo/Desktop/web-starter-kit/app/styles/components/_global.scss
    from line 10 of /home/riccardo/Desktop/web-starter-kit/app/styles/components/components.scss

at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/riccardo/Desktop/web-starter-kit/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/index.js:98:25)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
```

I mean it sounds really weird I haven't actually written any actual code and there it is a syntax error in code written by someone clever than me, but it's more plausible that I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the sass ruby gem. It compiles/converts easy to read code into css for you.

In a terminal/commandline go to the project folder and run `gem install sass`. (Assuming you have ruby installed). Then try running the gulp stuff again.

Hope that helps!